# Views Field View - No results behavior

Tags: 7, views

I have a view with 2 fields - one is another view, one is a node field. I do not want to display the parent view header when the inner view result set is empty and the node field does not have a value. "Display even if view has no result" is unchecked on the header settings but does not work because the parent view always has a result regardless of the presence of a value.

I am trying to add a PHP filter that checks for both criteria. I am running into the old issue that the $row object only contains node ids, but the $data object does not seem to work here, either. It only contains two properties, the view and the entity type of the attribute (called field_data_field_electronics_description_node_entity_type in this case).

So, this does not work for my filter code because the entity type is always set, even when the value is empty:

```
if ($row->view != NULL || 
   $data->field_data_field_electronics_description_node_entity_type != "" )   
{
   return FALSE;
}
else return TRUE;
```

This does not work because field_electronics_description always contains the node id, regardless of the presence of a value:

```
if ($row->view != NULL || $row->field_electronics_description != "" ) {
```

I don't see anything else in the $data object in devel that I could use. How can I suppress the parent view display?

Comment: Note to self: must load node again, for some weird reason. Millions of Drupal users have spent 10s of millions of person hours to figure this out.
https://www.drupal.org/node/1222448

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was - the node fields are not available and you have to reload the node, like so:

```
$nodef = node_load($data->nid);
$el = $nodef->field_electronics_description[und][0][value];

if ($row->view != NULL ||  $el != NULL) {
   return FALSE;
}
else return TRUE;
```